# Conflict installing XMind 3.6.0 from RPM on Fedora 23

Tags: fedora, alien

I am trying to solve problem installing **XMind 3.6.0 RPM on Fedora 23**.

I have downloaded the .deb package from XMind webpage.

Than, I have converted it to RPM package with Alien, to be able to install it on Fedora with help of [this manual](http://www.groesch.net/2014-02-08/alien-deb-rpm.html).

```
sudo alien -r -c xmind-3.6.0-2.x86_64.deb
```

and than install the generated RPM package

```
sudo rpm -ivh xmind-3.6.0-2.x86_64.rpm
```

but I keep getting the error message:

```
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
  file /usr/bin from install of xmind-3.6.0-2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-35.fc23.x86_64
  file /usr/lib from install of xmind-3.6.0-2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-35.fc23.x86_64
```

Does anybody know, how to resolve this conflict?

Thanks,
shimon

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to solve the error described in my post. However, I have found a way to install **XMind 7 (3.6.0) on Fedora 23**.

Following [this page](https://coderwall.com/p/9x63vg/mind-maps-setting-up-xmind-in-fedora-20).

The problem is, the xmind binaries structure has changed since this article. So the commands needed are little bit different.

1. Download Xmind portable version from Xmind web page - http://www.xmind.net/xmind/downloads/xmind7-portable-3.6.0.R-201511090408.zip
2. Extract it to directory ~/xmind_portable, then `cd ~/xmind_portable`
3. Untar the data.tar.gz `tar -xf data.tar.gz`
4. Move desktop launcher `sudo mv ./usr/share/applications/xmind.desktop /usr/share/applications`
5. `sudo mv ./usr/share/mime/packages/xmind.xml /usr/share/mime/packages/`
6. Move application data `sudo mv ./usr/lib/xmind/ /opt/`
7. Update mime DB `sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime/`

Make a link to your bin

```
sudo ln -s /opt/xmind/XMind /usr/local/bin/xmind
```

Then use it!

```
xmind
```